# How to get this simple layout done with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a container with a set width and height.
Within that container I have:

- a vertically and horizontally centered text
- a few vertically centered icons on the left side of the container
- a few vertically centered icons on the right side of the container

My test code:

```
.container {
width: 700px;
height: 70px;
border: 1px solid;
background-color: #ddd;
vertical-align:middle;
margin:auto;
}

.text {
display:inline-block;
font-size:18px;
text-align:center;
}

.iconsleft, .iconsright {
display:inline-block;
}

.iconsright {
right:0;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="iconsleft">
        <img src="https://www.tsf-showwelt.de/ticketportal/images.ticket/zoom_in.png">
        <img src="https://www.tsf-showwelt.de/ticketportal/images.ticket/zoom_in.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text">centered text</div>
    <div class="iconsright">
        <img src="https://www.tsf-showwelt.de/ticketportal/images.ticket/zoom_in.png">
        <img src="https://www.tsf-showwelt.de/ticketportal/images.ticket/zoom_in.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

(I took a random icon from google for this test)

This is what my test code looks like and what it should look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzQFz.jpg

### [CodePen](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/zHCLJ)

Comment: Use `block` for the images instead of `inline-block`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I try to avoid floats:

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/Gz4nv/1/

Things I did:

- Inserted Blank content which has its type set to `inline-block` (by default content added by css `content:'etc'` is inline element), and make it 100 percent the height of container, thus stretching the line height to height of container. So when i would `vertical-align` something it would see whole height of container as something to get aligned with.
- Declare container position as relative. Which would help in positioning icons absolutely. Because absolute positioning refers to first parent element that has been explicitly positioned relatively. `position:relative`.
- Than simply put `left:0;` on left container and `right:0;` on right one.
- make them both move down 50% the height of container.
- Then make them move them up 1/4th the height of container to bring them in center vertically by giving them **negative margin.**

Comment: take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/TfLTR/
I made it so regardless of dimmensions of parent and the div that needs to be centered it will remain in middle both vertically and horizontally even when any one of those change.

Answer (score 2):

### [Demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/eqEhr)

If you want the icons to go to one side, you should tell them to `float` in that direction.

The text isn't centered because it only takes up as much space as it needs.  Explicitly setting a width, will tell it to take up more space, and thus allow the text to be centered.  This could be in pixels or percentages.  For example if you have a container with width A and four images with width B (each), you could set the width to `A - 4B` pixels.

```
.text {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align:center;
  width: 80%;
}

.iconsleft, .iconsright {
  display:block;
}

.iconsright {
  float: right;
}
.iconsleft {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: center` needs to be set on the parent block, not the centered block, if you have `display: inline-block`.

Also `vertical-align:middle;` won't do you any good, unless you're in a table cell (or a div styled like one). If you want "real" vertical centering on IE7+ use good ol' tables, in conjnction with `vertical-align: middle`. Or just fake it with margins.

For `.iconsleft` and `.iconsright` use you might want to try floats, or `position: absolute`;

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin:auto;  
  text-align:center;
}

.text {
  font-size:18px;
  margin-top: 22px;
}

.iconsleft, .iconsright {
  margin: 20px 10px 0;
}

.iconsleft {
  float: left;
}

.iconsright {
  float: right;
}
```

HTML (floats need to be written before the content):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="iconsleft">
    <img src="https://www.tsf-showwelt.de/ticketportal/images.ticket/zoom_in.png" />
    <img src="https://www.tsf-showwelt.de/ticketportal/images.ticket/zoom_in.png" />
  </div>
    <div class="iconsright">
    <img src="https://www.tsf-showwelt.de/ticketportal/images.ticket/zoom_in.png" />
    <img src="https://www.tsf-showwelt.de/ticketportal/images.ticket/zoom_in.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="text">centered text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just float the two side `<div>`s to left and right, and put the right `<div>` before the centered `<div>` in the HTML structure.

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/KZxjW/)

```
<style>
.container {
width: 700px;
height: 70px;
border: 1px solid;
background-color: #ddd;
vertical-align:middle;
margin:auto;
}

.text {
font-size:18px;
text-align:center;
}

.iconsleft {float: left;}
.iconsright {float: right;}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="iconsleft">
        <img src="https://www.tsf-showwelt.de/ticketportal/images.ticket/zoom_in.png">
        <img src="https://www.tsf-showwelt.de/ticketportal/images.ticket/zoom_in.png">
    </div>
<div class="iconsright">
        <img src="https://www.tsf-showwelt.de/ticketportal/images.ticket/zoom_in.png">
        <img src="https://www.tsf-showwelt.de/ticketportal/images.ticket/zoom_in.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text">Centered demo text</div>
</div>
```

By changing the container height and giving it some bottom padding, you can make the full box vertically centered.

## [Bonus demo](http://jsfiddle.net/buEtc/)

Change `height: 70px;` in `.container` to this:

```
height: 50px;
padding-top: 20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jamescraig.info/stackoverflow/css/) with vertical and horizontal align.

I used a simple grid system to align everything up - CSS:

```
.grid {
    width:200px;
    height:70px;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/16x16">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/16x16">
</div>

<div class="grid text">centered text</div>

<div class="grid">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/16x16">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/16x16">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be the the perfect way but I think this hack might help:

```
.text {   
    display:inline-block;   
    font-size:18px;   
    text-align:center;  
    width: 80%;   
}  

.iconsleft, .iconsright, .text {   
    display:inline-block;   
    margin-top:20px;  
}   

.iconsright {  
    float: right;  
}   

.iconsleft {   
    float: left;  
}
```

Comment: In the future, I would recommend explaining in detail how this answer works.